# how to store data permanent in android application

Tags: android, json, database, facebook

1. In my application am getting Facebook information by using Facebook SDK and data stored in

variables then its working fine.But if am restart the mobile all variables are shows null(in log-cat)

and Application not working properly.

2. I am passing data to server like this

   ```
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
       HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);

           List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
           nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("firstname",firstname));
           nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lastname", lastname));

          httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

           HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
   ```

it gives response like this

```
{
      "message": "Successful",
    "data": {
        "user_id": 32,
        "firstname": "myname",
        "lastname": "lastname"
    }
 }
```

how can i get the user_id from above response or any other way.
Please tell me how can i solve these issues.Thanks in advance

Comment: create local database

Comment: Thakyou for response.how can i create local DB.First time am working on that, that's why am asking

Answer (score 1):

Store your values in `Preferences` or `SQLite` Database.

[Preferences](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm)

[android-preferences-tutorial](http://rominirani.com/android-preferences-tutorial/)

[Android SQLite](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html)

[Android SQLite Database](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_sqlite_database.htm)

Comment: how can i get the data from server responce

Comment: @user3814997 Just parse your data. Using `JSON` or `GSON`

Comment: i know how to pass data from application to server but i don't know how to get data from server response,please give me solution

Answer (score 0):

> *Hi,use* **SharedPreferences** *to store  data and you can access through out the app.*
>
> *start with initialize* **prefs**  i*n your Class constructor*

```
SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("com.namespace.pkg",
                        Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

> *and use two functions* **getPrefs()** *to get and* **setPrefs()** *to set values in sharedPreferences*

```
                public String getPrefs(String name) {
                    return prefs.getString(name, "");
                }

                public void setPrefs(String key, String value) {
                    prefs.edit().putString(key, value).commit();
                }
```